# Circular button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitableview

I would like to create a circular button in an `UITableViewCell`.
I am using `autolayout` constraints in IB.

Generally, I set the corner radius in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to keep the buttons circular despite the `autolayout`.

I have not found how to do that in an `UITableViewCell`. My buttons are diamond shape instead of oval ! :-(

Thanks !

here is how I make a button circular :

```
extension UIButton {
   func setCircular() {
      layer.cornerRadius = layer.frame.width / 2
   }
}
```

I do that in

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCellClass
    cell.goodButton.setCircular()
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us your code? The `cornerRadius` trick should work (the only concern is performance, since `conrnerRadius` isn't very fast).

Comment: set `cornerRadius` to half of your button's height or width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forget to add `self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true` on your class

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.makeItCircle()
}

func makeItCircle() {
    self.yourbutton.layer.masksToBounds = true 
    self.yourbutton.layer.cornerRadius  = CGFloat(roundf(Float(self.yourbutton.frame.size.width/2.0)))
}
```

for additional information see [this](https://theswiftdev.com/2015/12/02/collectionview-cells-with-circular-images/)

Comment: The real problem is that I have to make my buttons circular in `layoutSubviews()` and not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. Thank you !

Comment: You.  Saved.  My.  Life.  layoutSubviews ftw.

Answer (score 1):

If your Button height width is fixed
 you can use **User Defined Runtime Attributes** this will directly set corner radius from interface builder

Reference link 
[User Defined Runtime Attributes](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c/user-defined-runtime-attributes/)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
 goodButton.layer.cornerRadius = goodButton.layer.frame.height / 2
 goodButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Note: Please make sure your button has same width and height.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}
```

I use this extension in swift to set corner radius via Interface Builder. Hope it helps